# Is it possible to start an embedded facebook video at a specific point on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, facebook

Just at the title says, if I copy a link at a specific time, it gives m the time code t=###.

If I try to embed that video into wordpress, the video starts at the beginning.

Is there a way to start a facebook video at a specific time while embedded in Wordpress?

Comment: This is using the Embedded Video Player plugin, I suppose? That does not offer that as an option directly; but there is an API for it, so I guess you could try and implement something on your own, using the `seek` method to jump to the desired position. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-video-player/api

Comment: It seems the `t=` parameter works for facebook video url's too now: e.g. https://www.facebook.com/watch/?v=265933184844091&t=49

Answer (score 10):

It seems the `t=` parameter works for facebook video url's too now: e.g.

```
https://www.facebook.com/watch/?v=265933184844091&t=49
```

Answer (score 3):

This format rather than the `&t=` worked for me:

```
https://www.facebook.com/100003947034370/videos/1916436035164612/?t=1550
```

at least it works if you type or paste the url in your browser and I was able to send it via messenger, but if you try to post it on your timeline so that people can watch the video from the relevant point facebook in their infinite lack of wisdom replaces the time stamp with `?__tn__=R-R` and the video plays from the beginning.

Comment: april 2021, watching a video which was originaly a live stream, facebook rewrites that style of link to https://www.facebook.com/watch/live/?v=854520075334994 and the t= no longer works :(

Answer (score 0):

it works using links in the pc but not on phone (at least this is my experience: it remembers the point you where watching in any case and doesn't take into account the indication of &t=XX )